# Virtual VNC screen/workspace

Tags: ubuntu, vnc, virtual-desktop

I've got one monitor (the family TV) attached to my Ubuntu 8.04 system, and when I need to work on it I usually VPN into it from another PC.  However I'd like to be able to VPN in even when it's in use as the media center.

Is there a way to create a second virtual monitor/workspace that I could VNC into?  I know I could telnet in, but I want the GUI desktop.  The graphics card supports multiple screens - should I configure it for another monitor even though there is no other physical monitor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using FreeVNC:

If say your computer name is comp-user-01. You can VNC into a different session by using: comp-user-01:1

I believe you can set how many simultaneous users within the VNC server settings.

Edit: You can replace the last 1 with the number of the session you want to log into.

Comment: How do I start and configure the second session? I assume it should be running before I VNC into it (adding ":1" to my computer name doesn't automatically start a new session...does it?)

Comment: Actually I think it does. I think by specifying it, you create it. Not too sure.

Comment: Or you can start the server for the session by entering: "vncserver :2" on the host machine.

Comment: Thanks for the support.  OK, I installed tightvncserver and I'm able to start a new "desktop" just as you said.  However when I VNC into it it's just a terminal window, although it is in a resizeable GUI window.  But I don't have access to any of other Desktop features (menus to launch programs from, etc.).  It also looks like a different window manager on the second screen.  Is there a way I can make it become a "full" desktop?  I'm initially booting with xfce - it would be cool if I could run Gnome or KDE in the second instance - is that possible?

Comment: eek ... That I'm not sure of.

Comment: Thanks, Kazuma-san!  That (with Doug providing the final bit) was what I needed.  I'd give you both credit for the right answer if I could...

Answer (score 1):

Connect as discussed in Sakamoto Kazuma's answer.

You'll need an xstartup script in ~/.vnc/xstartup. It may already be there. If not, the standard one looks like:

```
#!/bin/sh

# Uncomment the following two lines for normal desktop:
# unset SESSION_MANAGER
# exec /etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc

[ -x /etc/vnc/xstartup ] && exec /etc/vnc/xstartup
[ -r $HOME/.Xresources ] && xrdb $HOME/.Xresources
xsetroot -solid grey
vncconfig -iconic &
xterm -geometry 80x24+10+10 -ls -title "$VNCDESKTOP Desktop" &
twm &
```

Now, uncomment the two lines starting with "# unset " and "# exec " (yeah-- those two just below the comment that says "Uncomment the following two lines for normal desktop"

That should give you your normal, Gnome desktop.

Comment: Thanks, that did it!  (Sorry it took me so long to try it out!)

Comment: Hmmm...the mouse works great, but whatever I type is getting scrambled: "drat" shows up as "fvan".  So I went back to edit ~/.vnc/xstartup (which originally didn't exist so I created it and pasted in your example) and it's been radically changed:

#!/bin/sh

xrdb $HOME/.Xresources
xsetroot -solid grey
#x-terminal-emulator -geometry 80x24+10+10 -ls -title "$VNCDESKTOP Desktop" &
#x-window-manager &
/etc/X11/Xsession 

Any idea what happened?

Comment: OK, the file I created per your instructions was ~/.vnc/xstartup.  The "radically changed" file I showed was from ~/vnc/xstartup.  Am I supposed to have both .vnc and vnc directories?  Which is the real one (I assume .vnc).  I'll figure this out eventually...

Comment: Discovered the answer to the keyboard mapping problem by adding 'export XKL_XMODMAP_DISABLE=1' in $HOME/.vnc/xstartup before the last line (/etc/X11/Xsession).  Discovered here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/vino/+bug/112955/comments/55