# How to run kubuntu 12 without monitor

Tags: display, vnc, kubuntu

I'm trying to setup home build server. I'm not experienced in linux thus I want to have remote access to GUI desktop. I installed kubuntu 12.04 (because I'm most familiar with it) and setup x11vnc. Everything worked fine until I disconnected monitor and restarted server. After that I'm still able to see desktop through vnc but it's really small. After some investigation I figured out that I need to setup kubuntu to run without real monitor.

Here are questions:

1. How to configure kubuntu to run without monitor (all instructions for ubuntu didn't work)?
2. Do you know any better way to achieve my goal?

I have little experience with linux, so I need detailed guidelines.

Comment: i'm thinking you would have to create a virtual monitor. not sure if this would help: http://superuser.com/questions/32455/virtual-vnc-screen-workspace